# Make equation number in middle with left alignment in latex

Tags: equations, alignment

I need to place the following bulk of equation to left alignment with keeping the equation number in the middle, however using `flalign` require set option on/off by line for equation number which at last will not be in the middle.

```
 \begin{flalign}
    \ell_1(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} ln(1- 
    \bm{P}_{ij}),&\nonumber\\
    \ell_2(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} ln\,\bm{P}_{id_i},&
 \end{flalign}
```

On the other hand, when using `aligned` with `equation`, equation number will be in the middle but the whole bulk of equation moved to center.

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
    \ell_1(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} ln(1- 
    \bm{P}_{ij}),\\
    \ell_2(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} ln\,\bm{P}_{id_i},
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

How can I keep the equation left aligned with equation number in the middle.

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear why a particular equation should be left aligned. If you want *all* equations to be left aligned, use the `fleqn` option.

Anyway, here's a way with `flalign`.

Function names such as “ln”, “sin”, “exp” should be typed in with a backslash: `\ln` and so on; this will give the correct spacing, besides using upright font shape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{flalign}
& \begin{aligned}
    \ell_1(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \ln(1-\bm{P}_{ij}),\\
    \ell_2(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \ln\bm{P}_{id_i},
 \end{aligned}
&&
\end{flalign}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know that setting `fleqn` as option in the document class make all equation left alignment, however I just want them  left alignment only in the proof appendix while all equation in all the thesis are in center alignment. However, I use your suggested solution by using `flalign` with `aligned` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: If I have a set of equations inside `fleqn` environment, how can I move the equation numbers to be next to them (instead of being at the right end of the line) and control the space between the equation and its number?

Answer (score 6):

Do note that the left-hand shift of the first set of equations is not caused by the use of `flalign`, *per se*. Instead, the shift is caused by the presence of additional `&` symbols.

To shift a nested `equation/aligned` system to the left, all you need to do is insert the instruction

```
\hspace*{6cm}\null  % choose offset amount suitably
```

between `\end{aligned}` and `\end{equation}`.

Oh, and do please write `\ln` rather than just `ln` to denote the natural logarithm operator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   \ell_1(\bm{\phi}) &= \sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \ln(1-\bm{P}_{ij}),\\
   \ell_2(\bm{\phi}) &= \sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \ln\bm{P}_{id_i},
\end{aligned}\hspace*{6cm}\null  % choose offset amount suitably
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You won for 35 seconds :-) Excellent and congratulations on your response.

Comment: Your solution also work perfect with me

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, which makes equations in the environment start at a fixed distance of the left margin via an optional argument (default 0pt):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[1em]
  \begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
    \ell_1(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \ln(1-
    \bm{P}_{ij}),\\
    \ell_2(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \ln\,\bm{P}_{id_i},
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! yes. Actually I didn't what the O.P. had written. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could, alternatively use, [`\usepackage{empheq}`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/empheq.pdf). Here I have added a picture of the differents environment (see the table) that you can use:
[image]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}{flalign}
  \begin{aligned}
    \ell_1(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \ln(1- 
    \bm{P}_{ij}),\\
    \ell_2(\bm{\phi})& =\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \ln\,\bm{P}_{id_i},
  \end{aligned}&&
\end{empheq}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact this package does not work with me. The equation still appears in center alignment.

Comment: Your LaTeX distribution will probably not be updated. Try to check the date of your version.

Comment: It seems that you'r right I will check for an update.

Comment: @ samcarter I did not update I used one solution of the suggested  above  and it works great with me